# GWT and PS3 browser (Netfront)

Tags: gwt, playstation3

Is anyone achieved loading GWT compiled app in PlayStation 3 (Netfront) browser? I have tried to compile IE6 only permutation, but PS3 did not pick it up. I think essentially the question is how to add new user.agent to GWT and map it to the existing IE configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify UserAgent.gwt.xml (  http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/UserAgent.gwt.xml  ) and use Conditional Properties ( http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ConditionalProperties )

```
<define-property name="ps3.user.agent" values="ps3, not_ps3" />
<property-provider name="ps3.user.agent"><![CDATA[
  {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (ua.indexOf('NetFront') != -1) { return 'ps3'; }
    return 'not_ps3';
  }
]]></property-provider>

<!-- Set user agent to ie6 if ps3 -->
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6" >
    <when-property-is name="ps3.user.agent" value="ps3" />
</set-property>
```

Relevant code in com.google.gwt.user.rebind.UserAgentPropertyGenerator
(
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/rebind/UserAgentPropertyGenerator.java )
You can edit this to have PS3 user agent return 'ie6', but I don't recommend this.